# Ansible - Add some calculated properties to list of dict

Tags: ansible

I am using a list of dict to declare some website to configure on web server.
There are some calculated properties I don't want to redeclare each time I need it, so before using it, I made a loop declaring all calculated/missing properties to get a proper list of websites (dict).

Here is what I am doing for now

```
- name: Set server vhosts
  set_fact:
    websites: "{{ websites|default([]) + [item | combine({'vhost': '200-' + item.name, 'path': path_vhosts + '/' + item.name, 'domain': app_hosts[item.name]})] }}"
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
```

But this is very limited, and will be unreadable if there is too much property to set.
How could I improve it to build it properly please ?

In a the best way, there is no variable vhosts, we just use websites and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Will be unreadable if there is too much property to set. How could I improve it to build it properly?"*
>
> A: It's built properly. The formatting might help. See below

```
- name: Set server vhosts
  set_fact:
    websites: "{{ websites|default([]) + [item|
                  combine({'vhost': '200-' + item.name,
                           'path': path_vhosts + '/' + item.name,
                           'domain': app_hosts[item.name]
                           }) ] }}"
  loop: "{{ vhosts }}"
```

Comment: Have you a solution to use variable in it ? Because I can not re-use calculated values.